# RSS Code Looks Good But unviewable in Browser

Tags: html, xml, xml-parsing

I am making an xml of a directory, but am having issues.  Everything seems fine, but when I uploaded it, nothing was viewable in my Browser Window.  I clicked on Page Source, and it showed all my code, but for some reason is not parsing it right.  Could someone check out what my issue is?  Working this to be an RSS FEED

http://www.316apps.com/NewallaSermons/Directory.xml

Comment: I suggest that you update your question to include that this is an RSS feed.  The reason being that your XML 'may' be fine, however it does not conform to RSS standards.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Judging by your xml, I would venture to guess that you are trying to put together an RSS feed.  I took the liberty of validating your RSS feed and there were errors.  View the validation errors using the source below.

Source: [Feed Validation Service](http://validator.w3.org/appc/check.cgi?url=http://www.316apps.com/NewallaSermons/Directory.xml)

Additional reading: [RSS 2.0 Specification](http://www.rssboard.org/rss-specification)

Comment: So how do I go about making those defined elements.  This is first venture in anything like that.

Comment: I think the question is whether or not you wish to use RSS.  RSS is a standard that must be adhered to according to the RSS Specification.  RSS readers recognize this standard.  If you want RSS readers to understand your xml, then you must go with the standards, else, you will need to create your own reader that does understand what to do with your defined elements.  That's not to say you can't use your information, you will need to figure out the best way to leverage the existing elements, like, `description`. You may also be interested in the ATOM Syndication Format.

Answer (score 0):

Though XML itself is extensible, specific applications (like RSS) are not (or they require special handling of extensions, like proper namespacing). If you want to use your own namespace, try Atom instead, but if you're just trying to get it to show something in the browser, it is fine to just stick exclusively with RSS spec elements.